# How to implement OracleDbType.Array and OracleDbType.Object in NHibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I have successfully implemented  SQLDbType.Structured  in SQL.But facing problem in OracleDbType.Array and  OracleDbType.Object .Any sample code which shows how to implement it using Nhibernate.

Following are my Procedure,Type and Object of Type which is IN parameter to my stored Procedure.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE employeeType AS OBJECT (employeeId INT, employeeName VARCHAR2    (50));     

   CREATE TYPE ttEmployeeType AS TABLE OF employeeType;   


  ***********Procedure***************************
  CREATE PROCEDURE testCustom (pLocation ttEmployeeType)   
     AS   
    BEGIN  
   INSERT INTO    employee (emp_id, emp_name)   
   SELECT  * FROM    TABLE(pLocation);  
   END;
```